# Org Agenda faces do not appear after applying themes

Tags: org-mode, faces, themes, org-agenda

In my Org Agenda all text except for priorities use the "default" face. Until recently I would see colourful text for say, todo status. I was playing around with custom themes, so I may have broken something. However I can't seem to undo this change, even after reverting all changes.

How can I make the Org Agenda use the correct faces instead of just using "default"?

Comment: The `*Org Agenda*` buffer/mode uses **text-properties**, not **font-lock**.  Enabling **font-lock** can have the effect of removing **text-properties** previously assigned.  It *may* be possible to use a theme with an `*Org Agenda*` buffer so long as **font-lock** is not enabled.  The theme would need to set the faces normally used by `org-agenda-mode`, which can also be set using the built-in customize user interface or set manually in the `.emacs` or other user-configuration file.

Comment: Thank you - the issue was that I had applied `rainbow-mode` globally, which turned on **font-lock** in the `*Org Agenda*`, which removed the **text-properties**. If you'd like to write a short answer I'd be happy to mark it as correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`org-agenda-mode` relies on setting `text-properties` for the faces that are used in the `*Org Agenda*` buffer.  When `org-agenda-mode` is enabled in the `*Org Agenda*` buffer, the following snippet is used to prevent `font-lock-mode` from being enabled:

```
;; Keep global-font-lock-mode from turning on font-lock-mode
(org-set-local 'font-lock-global-modes (list 'not major-mode))
```

Emacs does not do well when a marriage is attempted between `font-lock-mode` and `text-properties` to colorize text within a buffer.  It is *possible* to some degree (with a lot of work), but probably is not recommended (nor worth the effort, in the opinion of this author).  Thus, it is usually best to choose one or the other.

In this particular case, the original poster indicated that `font-lock-mode` was enabled by using `rainbow-mode`.  Disabling `rainbow-mode` thus resolved the issue.

Overlays play well with both `font-lock` and `text-properties`.  So perhaps the original poster could find a minor-mode that does not use `font-lock` to achieve the desired visual effect.

It is possible to create a custom `org-agenda-mode` that uses `font-lock` instead of `text-properties` [which is what this particular author has done], but that entails a lot of work and is ultimately a custom setup tailored to the needs of an individual user.

Comment: Thanks again for the comprehensive answer. Looking forward to you sharing your custom `org-agenda-mode` some time in the future :)