# Org agenda using default face for some things (not caused by font-lock)

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, faces, text-properties

Org agenda is using the default face for some items, preventing customization. I've seen [Org Agenda faces do not appear after applying themes](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/14316/org-agenda-faces-do-not-appear-after-applying-themes), but font-lock is not enabled for my agenda buffer (the value of `font-lock-mode` is `nil` there). The items it's using default face for are:

- Multi-day calendar events. For one-day or sub-day events, the face is set to `org-agenda-calendar-event` but where the event spans multiple days the entries of the form "(2/5): My Event" have the `face` text property set to `nil`.
- Upcoming deadline warnings when `org-agenda-skip-deadline-prewarning-if-scheduled` is set to `pre-scheduled`. If I set this variable to `nil`, the warnings have face `org-upcoming-deadline` but if I set it to `pre-scheduled` any upcoming deadlines that do show (because the item is scheduled) have the `face` text property set to `default` (not `nil`).

I've tried moving my `.emacs` aside and starting emacs in default configuration and these items still have default face.

Is it possible to configure the appearance of these items?

Comment: How about a fancy screen-shot with some arrows to help us visualize what portions you want to colorize differently?  Also, please indicate a version of `org-mode` -- as some people are using the built-in or older version, whereas others have the most recent version of `org-mode` that must be installed separately.